# Rewrite rule in addition to Wordpress'

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

So, I'm trying to add my own RewriteRule in addition to what Wordpress already has. A little backgroun. The site I am working on is built off of a custom CMS, but also has a blog that is powered by WordPress. So, heres what I have thus far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Custom rewrite for locatons
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)$  /locations2.php?info=$1

# Wordpress rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also got rid of a couple lines of the Wordpress Rewrite code that seemed unecessary (everything still works....I think). But yeah, it seems like it is overwriting the rule that I wrote. Help?

Oh, also, I just tried to get rid of the `.` that is before /blog/index.php [L] and replaced it with just a `^`, it worked...kind of. It loaded the blog when I went to /blog/, but when I went to something like /blog/author/admin, I got a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the last flag `[L]` after your new rule, otherwise processing will continue and your request will be rewritten to '/blog/index.php'.

```
RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)$  /locations2.php?info=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the `RewriteBase /` and the slash before locations2.php ?

Something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Custom rewrite for locatons
    RewriteRule ^locations/(.*)$  locations2.php?info=$1

    # Wordpress rewrite
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If the blog gets unreacheable, move `RewriteBase /` to after the custom rewrite. Also, I believe that if the blog is in a sub-directory, the RewriteBase should be `RewriteBase /blog/`